# How to make ansible return "ok" when python is installed in this playbook?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a playbook that looks like the following. It is supposed to install python onto the remote machine so that it can start using modules, hence why I have it using raw since it is the only thing that will run without a python interpreter.

```
---
- name: Checking Ansible Python Dependency
  hosts: Debian_Buster
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
  - name: install python 2
    become: yes
    raw: test -e /usr/bin/python || (apt -y update && apt install -y python-minimal)
```

This playbook task works as expected, but always returned "changed", even when nothing was installed.

Is there a way i can make this playbook return "ok" when `test -e /usr/bin/python` returns 0, and then return 'changed' when `test -e /usr/bin/python` returns 1?

Note: I can not use any other module other than raw because the python dependency is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic solution to this kind of problem makes use of the `register` keyword to save the result of the task, and then inspect the result in a `changed_when` expression.

In your case, we cannot use the return code alone to decide this, but we could just inspect the standard output, which, correct me if I am wrong, should only be empty if the `test` command succeeded.

Example:

```
- name: install python 2
  become: yes
  raw: test -e /usr/bin/python || (apt -y update && apt install -y python-minimal)
  register: command_result
  changed_when: command_result.stdout | length > 0
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed. I found the changed_when option and got it to work, but my play was much longer than yours. Thank you for showing me best practice :)